# Bash script: save last line output from terminal

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, shell-scripting

I am writing a bash script in which I would like to save the output of the last command in to a variable before running my next one so I can display it later.

I have tried a few different methods using tail with no success.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Knowing what you've tried would be a helpful first step in answering this.

Comment: I apologize, I was going to put some but I had tried several different ones, and by the time I got to asking this question it wasn't fresh in my mind anymore.
However for next time I will keep the code I have been trying in commented blocks so I can keep track...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer for what I am trying to do is like so:

`savedOuput=$(date)`

> This will save the output of the date command into the savedOutput variable.

'echo $savedOutput'

> Will print the contents that were saved on the 'savedOutput' variable

Comment: You should double-quote both `$(date)` and `$savedOutput`, to prevent problems with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the output of your last command  to a temporary file, using tee.

```
TMPPFILE=$( mktemp );
echo "First command" | tee ${TMPFILE};
echo "Second command" | tee ${TMPFILE};
echo "Third command" | tee ${TMPFILE}
```

Then:

```
cat ${TMPFILE}     ## Should produces the line below
Third command
```

Comment: Instead of redirecting the output to a file, one could directly save the output in the variable with a command substitution `MY_VAR=$(my_command)`.